# Proving there are no 4-digit number equal to the sum of the cubes of its digits.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In a nutshell, I'm trying to prove that there are no $a,b,c,d \in \{0,..,9\}$ with $a>0$ such that  $$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 = 10^3 a +10^2 b+ 10c +d = \overline{abcd}.$$

I've only been able to prove that if a solution were to exist, it must have $a=1$, since:

$$10^3 a +10^2 b+ 10c +d = a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 \leq 4 \cdot 9^3 = 2916 < 3\cdot10^3 \Rightarrow a\in\{1,2\}.$$

But $a\neq 2$, because if $a=2$ then:
$$2(10^3-2^2) = 1992 = b(b^2-100)+c(c^2-10)+d(d^2-1) \leq 0 + 9\cdot71 + 9 \cdot 80 = 1359,$$
which of course is a contradiction. So in the end, I'm stuck at proving that there are no $b,c,d \in \{0,...,9\}$ solution to:
$$\boxed{b^3 +c^3+d^3= 999+100b+10c+d}$$
or reordering:
$$\boxed{b(b^2-100)+c(c^2-10)+d(d^2-1) = 999}$$

Comment: the three digit example 153 is pretty famous. "while other scholars note that "no symbolic significance for the number of 153 fish in John 21:11 has received widespread support" $1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153$ in base ten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can see that the maximum sum of cubes of digits is $4 \cdot 9^3=2916$. Hence, the leading digit is at most $2$ and the number cannot be $2999$. Hence, the new maximum sum of cubes of digits is $$2^3+8^3+2\cdot9^3=1978$$
This means that the leading digit is $1$.

Assume that your number does not contain any $9$s. Then, the maximum sum is $1^3+3\cdot8^3=1537$. The second digit would be at most $5$. Repeating this, maximum is $1^3+5^3+2\cdot8^3=1150$. The second digit is at most $1$. The final repetition tells us that the max value is $2\cdot1^3+2\cdot8^3<1000$ which is a contradiction.

Hence, at least one of the digits is $9$. This already gives us a sum tally of $1^3+9^3=730$. Next, we know that $1,9,8,8$ as digits do not work. Hence, the maximum sum is:
$$\max(1^3+2\cdot9^3+7^3,1^3+9^3+2\cdot8^3)=\max(1802,1754)=1802$$
And since $1,9,9,7$ as digits don't work either, we can see that the number must be less than $1800$. This means that the second digit is at most $7$ and $9$ must come either in the tens or units digit.

As $1,9,9,7$ do not work, the next maximum is $\max(1^3+2\cdot9^3+6^3,1^3+7^3+8^3+9^3)=1675$. Second digit is at most $6$. Applying again, knowing that $1,9,9,6$ as digits don't work, we will have the next maximum at $1^3+2\cdot9^3+5^3=1584$. Hence, the second digit is at most $5$. Since $1,5,9,9$ and $1,4,9,9$ both fail, the new maximum is $\max(1^3+5^3+8^3+9^3,1^3+2\cdot9^3+3^3)=1486$. This shows that the second digit is at most $4$.

If the number has a second $9$, then the sum already becomes $1^3+2\cdot9^3>1400$, and since $1499$ fails, this is a contradiction. Hence, there exists exactly one $9$ in the number. The maximum sum of cubes of digits is $1^3+4^3+8^3+9^3=1306$, which shows the second digit is at most $3$. Applied once more gives a maximum of $1269$, showing that the second digit is at most $2$.

If $2$ is the second digit, then since $1,2,8,9$ fail, the maximum is $1^3+2^3+7^3+9^3<1200$. If the second digit is $1$, then we may easily verify that we have:
$$1^3+1^3+9^3+7^3<1100<1200<1^3+1^3+9^3+8^3$$
giving a contradiction. Thus, the second digit must be $0$. For the sum of cubes of the digits, three of them being $1,0,9$, to be between $1000$ and $1100$, the fourth digit (not necessarily last) must be $7$. Since this fails, we conclude that there are no solutions.